# JAL: what is the "alternate link register" x5 for?

Tags: riscv

The RISC-V specification v2.2 (JAL instruction, page 15) says of the "standard calling convention":

> The standard software calling convention uses x1 as the return address register and x5 as an alternate link register.

with the following design comment:

> The alternate link register supports calling millicode routines (e.g., those to save and restore
>   registers in compressed code) while preserving the regular return address register.

What is an alternative link register for?

I understand that "link register" is a register to store the pc to jump to on return, and that millicode/microcode are a lower-level instruction format below the ISA level. Is the idea that `x5` is used *instead of `x1`* for certain (microcode/millicode) instructions that surround "normal calls" to avoid register shuffling or a spill? Would you have a typical usage example?

It could be helpful to add an explanation of alternate link registers to the Wikipedia article on [link registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_register), which is where I went looking for extra information.

Comment: If nobody can answer this in the near future, you could also ask this in the sw-dev mailinglist.

Comment: @gasche I was wondering if you got any updates regarding the answer? If yes, can you please share?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general millicode instructions shouldn't intersect with normal instructions and an alternative calling convention is needed to call a millicode procedure ([from Waterman's PhD Thesis, page 66](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/etd/ucb/text/Waterman_berkeley_0028E_15908.pdf)):

> ... routines must
>   have an alternate calling convention since the link register must be preserved during their
>   execution. Fortunately, unlike ARM and MIPS, RISC-V’s jump-and-link instruction can
>   write the return address to any integer register, rather than clobbering the ABI-designated
>   link register. Other than that distinction, these millicode routines behave like ordinary
>   procedures

A more specific reason, why the link register should be preserved, is because the millicode is used to implement prologues and epilogues, thus using a regular calling convention will clobber the link register and will defeat the whole idea of using millicode for prologues/epilogues.

> Is the idea that x5 is used instead of x1 for certain (microcode/millicode) instructions that surround "normal calls" to avoid register shuffling or a spill?

Yes... to some extent of the word "surround".

> Would you have a typical usage example?

See `prologue_2`, `epilogue_2` millicode routines from [Waterman's PhD, page 67](http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/etd/ucb/text/Waterman_berkeley_0028E_15908.pdf)

```
00: c919     c.beqz a0, 16
02: 016002ef jal t0, prologue_2
06: 842a     c.mv s0, a0
08: 157d     c.addi a0, -1
0a: ff7ff0ef jal ra, factorial
0e: 02850533 mul a0, a0, s0
12: 0100006f jal x0, epilogue_2
16: 4505     c.li a0, 1
18: 8082     c.jr ra
```

where `prologue_2`:

```
00: 1141 c.addi sp, -16
02: e406 c.sdsp ra, 8(sp)
04: e022 c.sdsp s0, 0(sp)
06: 8282 c.jr t0
```

and `epilogue_2`:

```
00: 60a2 c.ldsp ra, 8(sp)
02: 6402 c.ldsp s0, 0(sp)
04: 0141 c.addi sp, 16
06: 8082 c.jr ra
```

Comment: Perhaps it's worth to note that RISC-V millicode implementations 'take the form of normal RISC-V instructions' (Footnote 11, page 66) - i.e. it isn't 'a lower-level instruction format below the ISA level'  as suspected by the OP.

Comment: For anyone looking for an unbroken link to Waterman's PhD thesis: 
 https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~krste/papers/EECS-2016-1.pdf