# risc-v official doc p20, what does 'one bit different' mean with `x5` and `x1`?

Tags: cpu-registers, riscv

I have read this somewhat related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556354/jal-what-is-the-alternate-link-register-x5-for) and official doc section 'Unconditional Jumps', but still not know **one bit different** mean?

> The register
> x5 was chosen as the alternate link register as it maps to a temporary in the standard calling
> convention, and has an encoding that is only **one bit different** than the regular link register.

Comment: It means that a single bit (one-eighth of a byte) is different between them. A single bit difference is the difference between the binary numbers `1001`, `1011` and `1101`.

Comment: Yes, I understand after reading your comment. This may simplify hardware design which the doc highly emphasize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Based on the above comments, 'A single bit difference is the difference between the binary numbers 1001, 1011 and 1101'

The question is marked as solved now.